# How do I prevent string keys from being converted to symbols in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, key

I'm using Rails 4.2.  I noticed when I try and create an array of hashes, it seems my string keys are getting converted to symbols ...

```
> my_hash_arr = [{"name": "DA", "amount": 100000 }]
=> [{:name=>"DA", :amount=>100000}]
```

I don't want this.  I want my key "name", to remain as a string and not be converted to a symbol key.  How do I structure my array so this conversion doesn't take place.

Comment: `{ "name": "DA" }` is the same as `{ name: "DA" }` and is shown by Ruby as `{ :name => "DA" }`. The use of a colon only applies when the key is a symbol. It is provided as a convenience because keys are often symbols. The quotes are needed when the the key contains whitespace or begins with with a character other than a letter or underderscore. For example, `{ '1name': "DA" }` is OK but `{ 1name: "DA" } #=> SyntaxError: <main>: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method`. Note one can write `{"my name": "DA", :amount=>100000 }`, but `{:"my name"=>"DA", :amount=>100000 }` is preferred.

Comment: The JavaScript-style colon for hash keys is not an alternative to the hashrocket for creating hashes, it is an alternative to creating symbol keys, sometimes symbol literals are quoted  (i.e. `{ k: v }` and `{ :k => v }` and `{ 'k': v }` are equivalent, `{ 'k' => v }` and `{ 'k': v }` are different).

Comment: You are using Ruby's [hash syntax](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Hashes) for symbol keys, it's expected that your keys are symbols.

Comment: @stefan it's not just expected - Ruby will actually coerce the keys into symbols.

Comment: @max with the symbols literal, Ruby interprets the key-part as a symbol right-away. There's no intermediate string. With "it's expected" I wanted to say that you can't expect anything but symbols when using the symbols literal :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want that, the correct syntax is changing `:` to `=>` like this:

```
 my_hash_arr = [{"name" => "DA", "amount" => 100000 }]
=> [{"name"=>"DA", "amount"=>100000}]
```